# efficient way of printing lists to a table in a .txt file using python

Tags: python, list, printing

I want to create a text file which contains a table, created from lists. But, I don't want to have to do something like this:

```
import string
print >> textfile, string.rjust(listname[0],3), string.rjust(listname[1],3),
```

The following code demonstrates the idea of what I would like to do, but doesn't work:

```
import string
listname = ['test1','test2','test3']
i=0
for i in range(0,3):
   print >> textfile, string.rjust(listname[i],5)
```

I would like the output to look exactly like this:

```
test1   test2   test3
```

That's what I'm trying to do and how it makes sense in my head, but obviously that won't (and isn't) working.

I've used the `join()` function to print the lists nicely, but I can't get the spacing right for the table.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding the problem correctly, you could just do this...

```
>>> def print_table():
...     headers = ['One', 'Two', 'Three']
...     table = [['test1', 2, 3.0],
...             ['test4', 5, 6.0],
...             ['test7', 8, 9.0],
...             ]
...     print ''.join(column.rjust(10) for column in headers)
...     for row in table:
...         print ''.join(str(column).rjust(10) for column in row)
... 
>>> 
>>> print_table()
       One       Two     Three
     test1         2       3.0
     test4         5       6.0
     test7         8       9.0
>>>
```

No need for the `string` module or integers to index into the table.

I've printed to standard out for clarity, but you can write to a file just as easily.

Comment: In my table, I'm trying to print headers for the table, so strings, then beneath those headers, variables which represent integers. And I get the following `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple`

Comment: I've updated my example to display headers. What are you using as your list index?

Comment: Thanks. It's giving a syntax error for the ':' after the for loop though. I'm doing something little wrong lol.
And I'm using a range of values for my index

Comment: A `SyntaxError`? This was copied and pasted straight from a Python interactive session! Also my example does not index into a `list` and I see no reason why you'd need to.

Comment: Here is what I've tried: `def print_table():
    headers=['Student','Final','Exam1','Exam2','Pwa','ILGQ','GLGQ']
    table=[`finalx`,`exam1`,`exam2`,`pwa`,`ilgq`,`glgq`]
    print ''.join(column.rjust(10) for column in headers)
    for row in table:
        print ''.join(str(column).rjust(10) for column in row)
print_table()`

And my result is now good, except the "table" values are not printed in a table but on separate lines

Comment: My "`table`" is a `list` of `lists`. Yours is a flat `list`, which my code would tread as one column per row.

Comment: That solved the problem, it works perfectly now. Thanks for your patience, I really appreciate it! I miss small details when I'm sleepy

Answer (score 1):

Think most effective way is to generate string using `.join` method and then do one write operation to the file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
so something like `'%s' % '||'.join(titles)` if the list name was titles, then write that? How could I space it nicely in a more tabulated manner though?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean it isn't working?

First of all, `rjust` is going to include the characters in the string. It looks like you want a `rjust` of at around 8 to get the spacing you are looking for with strings like `"test1"`.

Second, because your print has no comma at the end of it, it will print each one on a new line. You probably want something like:

```
print >> textfile, string.rjust(listname[i],8),
```

Then, after you are out of the loop you need to print a newline:

```
print >> textfile
```

Now, we have some whitespace at the beginning of the line because we `rjust` the first item in the list. You actually probably want this behavior, because then the columns will line up, the other option is to use `ljust`.

---

Some minor style suggestions:

- `i=0` does nothing here; it will get overwritten
- `for item in listname` is likely better than the `range` thing you are doing.
- instead of `string.rjust`, you should just call `rjust` on the string itself, like: `listname[i].rjust(8)`

---

If you want to be slick with `join` and a list comprehension, you could do:

```
print >> textfile, ' '.join(item.rjust(8) for item in listname)
```

This does an `rjust` on all the items, then joins them together with a space (you could use empty string here, as well).

Comment: It isn't working because listname[i] is expecting a value or something, not a list. I'll see if I can re-produce the error really quick

Comment: Hmm. I tried it earlier and it simply wouldn't work. I must've done something differently, because it's more or less working correctly now.Thanks!

Comment: Here is what I have `i=0
for i in range(0,8):
    print >> report, titles[i].center(8),
i=0
for i in range(0,8):
    print >> report,"\n", values[i].rjust(8),
report.close()
` and it's not printing values[i] to the same line :/